# r.Viewshed GRASS function returns NaN insteat of 0 and 1 for 1 in -b Boolean Mode

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, viewshed

r.Viewshed GRASS function returns NaN insteat of 0 and 1 for 1, 
i am not not able to recode NaN Values to 0 with r.recode function. 
How to reclassify or recode raster from 0 to 1? pl. Help 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Even though you did not tag your question as GRASS related, you refer to GRASS modules, so this answer is based on GRASS.

You can use the `r.null` module with the parameter `null=0`. This will convert all NULL values to zero. So it will be:

```
r.null map=view null=0
```